# Can just anyone change the accounts and total supply?

Tags: nearprotocol

In fungible token:

```
pub struct FungibleToken {
    /// sha256(AccountID) -> Account details.
    pub accounts: UnorderedMap<Vec<u8>, Account>,

    /// Total supply of the all token.
    pub total_supply: Balance,
}
```

https://github.com/near-examples/FT/blob/master/contracts/rust/src/lib.rs

accounts and total supply is marked public, can't just anyone is able to change the accounts and total_supply

Does the blockchain chain only allows to access functions?
But I am able to change the variables in tests.

Comment: The short answer is no. If you think you can modify these variables publicly, please post your code.

Comment: Tests were allowing it to modify it, that's why the question. near-api-js only allows functions, not struct variables.

Comment: I'll allow folks more involved in the bindgen side to chime in, but in short: no, not just anyone can change the public variables of a struct.

Comment: maybe confusion comes from the fact that owner is not stored in contract state but rather derived from the runtime itself in each method:
example: let owner_id = env::predecessor_account_id();